# Is it costly to have too many redux stores?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-state

Currently, each of my components' state is stored in `useState` hooks. I want to be able to persist the states of all my components so that when a user navigates back to a previous page, etc., they will pick up where they left off.

Is this too costly?

Comment: Does each new object / state have an associated overhead in the form of computational and/or memory cost? Yes. Is that overhead completely negligible compared to the clarity provided by separation of concerns in your application's source code? Absolutely. ["Make it work, make it right, make it fast"](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)

Answer (score 1):

With Redux you don't have multiple stores, you have a single store that maintains a global redux state.

You use that state within your component be using a *selector*, as such:

```js
const bar = useSelector(state => state.foo.bar)
```

Your component will only rerender when the individual sub-state you select changes.

Redux is performant, and you can have a lot of state within it without causing any performance issues. However, you generally don't want to offload *everything* to Redux, because it has development overhead, and because some state is more logically scoped to an individual component.

tl;dr; it's not costly to have a lot of state in your Redux store as opposed to using `useState`

Comment: by a single store, do you mean only one `configureStore` is ever created?

Comment: so i guess by multiple stores, what I meant is multiple `createSlice`.

Comment: Correct, only one `configureStore`, with multiple reducers (defined probably in different files using `createSlice`).